# undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass Did you mean? tap - How to fix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

I am making a Rails application, which will have something as "products" on it. Products will have a photo, name, category, code and description.

I've tried many ways but none worked.

Products_controller's NEW and CREATE methods:

```
def new
    if !logged_in?
        redirect_to root_path
    end
    if logged_in?
        @product = current_user.products.build
        @categories = Category.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }
    end
end 
def create
    @product = current_user.products.build(product_params) 
    @product.category_id = params[:category_id]
    if @product.save
        redirect_to root_path
    else 
        render 'new'
    end
```

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<div class="deniso">

<% <h1>Shto Produkt:</h1>
   <%= simple_form_for @product, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
<%= f.file_field :product_img %>
 <div class="cate">  
   <%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories), :prompt => "Zgjidhni kategorine:") %>
  </div> 
  <h4>Emri i produktit</h4>
   <%= f.input :title, label: "Emri i Produktit:" %>
   <h4>Kodi</h4>
   <%= f.input :kodi, label: "Kodi:" %>
   <h4>Qmimi<h4>
   <%= f.input :qmimi, label: "Qmimi:" %>
   <h4>Pershkrimi</h4>
   <%= f.input :pershkrimi, label: "Pershkrimi:" %>
   <div class="btn btn-1">
   <%= f.button :submit %>
   </div>
   <% end %>
   </div>

    <%= link_to "Kthehuni mbrapa", root_path, class: "btn-custom2" %>

    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

ERROR CODE:

```
NoMethodError in Products#create
Showing C:/Users/PC/Desktop/Npshkodra/app/views/products/new.html.erb where line #12 raised:

undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  tap
<%= f.file_field :product_img %>
 <div class="cate">  
   <%= select_tag(:category_id, options_for_select(@categories), :prompt => "Zgjidhni kategorine:") %>
  </div> 
  <h4>Emri i produktit</h4>
   <%= f.input :title, label: "Emri i Produktit:" %>
```

I expect that product will be created.

EDIT:
I've tried to declare `@categories` on `create` method, but still it's not working:

````
      @categories = Category.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }
       @product = current_user.products.build(product_params) 
       @product.category_id = params[:category_id]
       if @product.save
           redirect_to root_path
       else 
           render 'new'
       end
    end 
     ```
````

Comment: What's the full stacktrace of the error?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/eJIyKBO

Comment: The problem is that `@categories` is `nil` because you haven't defined it in your `create` method.

Comment: Hw to fix it then?

Comment: "it's still not working" ... is there a different error? Same error?

Comment: What's the error you mentioned in this sentence, I believe it should be another error?  `: I've tried to declare @categories on create method, but still it's not working:`

Answer (score 0):

Check the `map` call in your `new` method.
`@categories = Category.all.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }`
It might be the cause of the error. 'AсtiveRecord' returns an empty array if no records found but I would verify the output anyway in case something unexpected happened.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are receiving nil from AR query. To handle such errors you can try this:

```
@categories = Category.all.to_a.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id]}
```

But the results will be 0 since there are not any.